# phpMyAdmin displays blank page

Tags: mysql, php

I have gone through all links related to a blank page displayed by phpMyAdmin but none of them helped my solve my issue.

I have installed phpMyAdmin and deployed it on the Apache server. I have also successfully installed PHP 5.6 and PHP files get displayed properly.

After the installation, I tried accessing the following URL:

```
http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/
```

It displays a blank page with just the icon. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: provide more information.

Comment: i mean i can only see a blank page. I tried inspecting elements and i see few div's which are hidden. logs of appache doesn't have anything in particular...                                              "Child 83432: Starting thread to listen on port 80." when i see "network" in developer tools of chrome it says 200 OK...Am not even sure what am i missig

Comment: apache error logs?

Comment: yes what else i need to check exactly? I mean i am following "http://www.wikihow.com/Install-phpMyAdmin-on-Your-Windows-PC". Pleaes suggest

Comment: Find out the error, check the error.log. It should be someplace like /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/httpd/error_log, etc. Sometimes a vhost-specific error log file. There should be a clear indication about the problem. Also test with 'curl -v URL >/dev/null' to see the response status and body content, "blank page" is of no use and browsers are not good diagnostic tools.

Comment: try run `php index.php` in `CLI`, you'll get error right there..

Comment: zerodeux - he is under windows

Comment: i dont see any errors in logs and yes am in windows...

Comment: iam unable to run "php index.php" ,says php is not recognised as an internal or external command. But one thing here,my php is configured properly for sure, since if i add phpinfo() in my php file it prints the details

Comment: ran the command which you said and it gave me the error ..syntax error in config.inc.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do better debugging), try run `php index.php` in `CLI`, you'll get error right there..

Comment: That the only things that helps. For some reason even with error_reporting E_ALL and display_errors* On it didn't showed the error in config file.